# UITapGestureRecognizer in UITableViewCell are not recognized

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I made a quite a bit customized `UITableView` which has 3 rows, each row is custom made using `UITableViewCell`. I added several `UIView`s within `UITableViewCell` along with `UITapGestureRecognizer`s.

Due to many small views in `UITableViewCell`, I implemented codes for touch events on "m" file of that `UITableViewCell`.

Somehow the recognizer are not working. I am not sure I am providing enough info here..

UPDATE: I realized my explanation isn't quite enough.. so a little more detail.

This is how my `UITableView` look like,

`UITableView` has `UITableViewCell`(A). 
`UItableViewCell`(A)'s contentView is made by combination of 6 other `UITableViewCells`(B).
Each `UITableViewCells`(B) has a few `UIViews` which have those TapGesture recognizers.

I know it seems over complicated, but I used UITableViewCell(B) not for reuse purpose but for repeated Nib files. Anyway the final UIView doesn't take any touch events.

Comment: Remember that `UITableViewControllers` have a gesture of their own on the `UIScrollView`. Not an answer, but should help get you where you need to be.

Comment: it is not possible to detect the tap on uitableview as it has its own tap gesture.

Comment: Try setting `userInteractionEnabled = YES` and also `exclusiveTouch = YES` on your **UIViews**.

Comment: Do you find the solution for your problem

Comment: No, but I think I have some clues... I streamlined the number of views in between, now I am getting random crash when tapped anywhere the cell. I still don't understand what's going on thoroughly.

Comment: Did you solve your problem. If you find my answer help you out then can you accept and upvote please

Comment: Did you solve the problem

Comment: Yes, eventually, I found the solution by setting UIGestureRecognizer delegate, which control simultaneous touch events.

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView` has its own tap gesture for selecting the row. You can do it by implementing your code inside following functions. Can you tell me what are you using to implement for selecting the row

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```